# Non-concurrent O(1) space solution for Leaf-Similar Trees Leetcode Problem

Tags: algorithm, go, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to solve [Leaf-Similar Trees](https://leetcode.com/problems/leaf-similar-trees/) problem on leetcode.com with O(1) space **without concurrency/goroutines**.

Iterative solution needs a stack for storing nodes, and a recursive one needs memory for function calls.

However, with the help of the Morris Traversal algorithm, I was able to traverse each tree with O(1) memory (which was tricky btw, as it is non-trivial to detect leafs with this algorithm).

Now I have a problem of how to traverse both trees and compare that 1) they have the same number of leafs and 2) in the same order.

The obvious way is to store both sequences of leafs in arrays/slices and then compare those. However, it ruins the O(1) memory. I can also store the first tree sequence in an array, and yield the values from the second tree one by one, comparing them to the values in an array, but it still violates O(1).

So I cheated by using goroutines to send the values from both Morris traversals, effectively creating no intermediate arrays and achieving O(1) space.

Now I am trying to make this solution more generic by **not using goroutines** or any other concurrency techniques. It must be a sequential solution.

Alternatively, I have suspicion that it is not possible to make this work without concurrency, please confirm if it is true.

Here is my solution:

```golang
func leafSimilar(root1 *TreeNode, root2 *TreeNode) bool {
    getLeafs := func(node *TreeNode, ch chan int) {
        var pre *TreeNode // predecessor of the current node
        curr := node
        
        for curr != nil {           
            if curr.Left == nil {
                if curr.Right == nil {
                    ch <- curr.Val
                }
                curr = curr.Right
                continue
            }
            
            // curr.Right != nil
            pre = curr.Left
            for pre.Right != nil && pre.Right != curr {
                pre = pre.Right
            }
            
            if pre.Right == nil {
                pre.Right = curr
                curr = curr.Left
                continue
            }
            
            // pre.Right == curr
            pre.Right = nil
            if pre.Left == nil { // tricky! not using curr, but pre
                ch <- pre.Val
            }
            curr = curr.Right
        }
        
        close(ch)
    }
    
    ch1 := make(chan int)
    ch2 := make(chan int)
    
    go getLeafs(root1, ch1)
    go getLeafs(root2, ch2)
    
    similar := true
    
    for {
        val1, ok1 := <-ch1
        val2, ok2 := <-ch2
        
        if val1 != val2 || ok1 != ok2 {
            similar = false
        }
        
        if ok1 == false && ok2 == false {
            break
        }
    }
    
    return similar
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can work without concurrency, and still fit within your criteria. It's not pretty but it seems to work...

```
func leafSimilarNoConcurrency(root1 *TreeNode, root2 *TreeNode) bool {
    if root1 == root2 {
        return true
    }
    getLeafs := func(curr *TreeNode, pre *TreeNode) (int, *TreeNode, *TreeNode, bool) {
        for curr != nil {
            if curr.Left == nil {
                if curr.Right == nil {
                    //ch <- curr.Val
                    return curr.Val, curr.Right, pre, true
                }
                curr = curr.Right
                continue
            }

            // curr.Right != nil
            pre = curr.Left
            for pre.Right != nil && pre.Right != curr {
                pre = pre.Right
            }

            if pre.Right == nil {
                pre.Right = curr
                curr = curr.Left
                continue
            }

            // pre.Right == curr
            pre.Right = nil
            if pre.Left == nil { // tricky! not using curr, but pre
                // ch <- pre.Val
                return pre.Val, curr.Right, pre, true
            }
            curr = curr.Right
        }

        return 0, nil, nil, false
    }

    var val1, val2 int
    var pre1, pre2 *TreeNode
    var ok1, ok2 bool
    curr1, curr2 := root1, root2

    similar := true

    for {
        val1, curr1, pre1, ok1 = getLeafs(curr1, pre1)
        val2, curr2, pre2, ok2 = getLeafs(curr2, pre2)

        if val1 != val2 || ok1 != ok2 {
            similar = false
        }

        if ok1 == false && ok2 == false {
            break
        }
    }

    return similar
}
```

Performing a little benchmarking, it may even be faster (at least for the example1 test case)...

```
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkLeafSimilar-4                    244850          5509 ns/op         192 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkLeafSimilarNoConcurrency-4     13185218            92.9 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      _/d_/Build/morristree   2.893s
```

I've put together an example which uses the deprecated testing.Main in the playground here, to demonstrate that it works the same for the 5 examples.

https://play.golang.org/p/hIk4zM3qpsT

Comment: Amazing solution, I will need some time digging into it to understand it completely. It passes all tests on leetcode. If you don't mind, I have a question: with my experiments with Morris Traversal, I found that returning before the traversal ends leads to the traversed tree to be left in altered state (with temp connections still there). Therefore, I was "pausing" with channels in two points where you return results. How does returning work in your solution? Do you return `curr` every time and come back to it and the tree stays modified between the function calls?
Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Yeah, it's probably not something I'd use in Production as the modifying nature of the traversal operation might trip someone up in future, if they called it in two threads/processes simultaneously. But have fun!